# Arrays and min values

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Currently working on a project where I have two arrays (one 1-D and another 2-D). One contains names and another contains a set of numbers. I'm working on a function that finds the lowest value in the table and outputs it. However, I need to attribute the name of the monkey to the amount of food he has eaten. So "Monkey 1 has eaten the least amount of food only eating 11 pounds on Day 1". Below is the function to find the lowest value which is working fine, however I'm not sure how to implement the monkey's name (without just typing it in) and the day of the week. If the rest of my code is needed please let me know.

```
void leastAmt(string names[], int food[][NUM_DAYS])
{
int lowest = food[0][0];
for (int monkey = 0; monkey < NUM_MONKEYS; monkey++)
{
    for (int day = 0; day < NUM_DAYS; day++)
    {
        if (food[monkey][day] < lowest)
            lowest = food[monkey][day];
    }

}
cout << "Least amount of food: " << lowest << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the relation(s) between monkey name, day and eaten food?

Comment: Monkey eats food each day of the week so my table would look something like: 

Name:                  Day 1                 Day 2              Day 3

Monkey 1              44lbs                  22lbs              35lbs

Monkey 2              32lbs                   55 lbs             52lbs 

etc.

Comment: State the problem clearly

Comment: So from all the days you want to find the index of the monkey that eat the least on one particular day ?

Comment: Basically, I want to find which monkey eat the least amount and which day he eat the least amount. So if he ate 11 pounds on Day 3 and that's the lowest amount out of the entire array, I want to be able to find that and display it.

Comment: So is this taking all the monkeys into account (@AnilVedala's solution seems to satisfy your requirement)  ___or___ for all monkeys individually ?

Comment: It would better if you can come up with some sample example. You problem statement is obscure.

Comment: @vin yes you are correct, Anil's solution did work. Sorry for being so obscure, was having a hard time describing the issue. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create two variables for storing monkey and money values.

```
int lowest_monkey, least_day;
```

Whenever lowest value is modified update these values with current values of monkey and day variables.
Replace the last line with the following

```
cout << "Monkey " << lowest_monkey << " has eaten least amount of food only eating " << lowest << " on " << least_day << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store least_eating_monkey in an array, storing monkey names for each day.

```
int leastEatingMonkey[NUM_DAYS];
for (int day = 0; day < NUM_DAYS; day++)
{
  lowest = INT_MAX;
  for (int monkey = 0; monkey < NUM_MONKEYS; monkey++)
  {
     if (food[monkey][day] < lowest){
         leastEatingMonkey[day] = monkey;   
         lowest = food[monkey][day];
     }
  } 
} 
for (int day = 0; day < NUM_DAYS; day++)
{
  cout << "monkey " << names[day] << " ate least amount of food on day " << day << endl;
}
```